# R syntax: Move rows of participant A to the end of the first row of participant A

Tags: r

Unfortunately, I'm totally lost with R. I grew up with SPSS, which I really regret right now.

My problem:

1. I have several Excel files
2. In each file I have several rows, which belong to one specific participant. Each row consists of several columns. E.g. for participant A several rows with several columns, for participant B several rows with several columns and so on
3. My goal is to have just one row for each participant with all the data in columns
4. This means, I need a syntax which moves the second row of participant A (and so on) to the column end of the first row
5. Afterwards the next row of participant A needs to be moved to the end of the first row. This should be iterated until I have only one row for participant A with all the data in columns.
6. Then I need to do same for participant B, C and so on

Is there a possibility to do this with r? I'm so lost.

Best,
Jonas

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Let's assume you can correctly import your data so skip the Excel file part.

Comment: Do you have the id for the participant in each of the rows? Do the rows within participant have individual identifiers?  Would be good to show some sample rows (maybe for 2 people and just a few columns each) and then what you would like the final outcome to be.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I'll look into the reproducible example tomorrow (it's late here). When you click on the [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1f3C-Qxub6ojPGbnsywsx9kuzndBwXITm)  you see two screenshots which show you how it should look like for participant "kg01t2". It's from Excel but I think you'll get the idea.

Thank you again. I'm so happy that I got a reply. My mood is better again.

Best,
Jonas

Comment: Don't feel discouraged if you get down votes, when you edit your question to follow the standard format (no screenshots please) people will take off the down votes.